# Angular 7: Access list element in an array

Tags: angular, typescript, arraylist

I'm trying to get one component of a list. The list is in an array. How do I get one specific component of the list? In this case I'm trying to get the 'source' element of hierarchialGraph.links.

Code:
Typescript of the array (just a snippet):

```
showGraph() {
    this.hierarchialGraph.nodes = [
      {
        id: '1',
        label: '1',
        position: 'x1'
      }
       ....
    ];

    this.hierarchialGraph.links = [
      {
        source: '1',
        target: '2',
        label: '1'
      }
       ....
    ];
  }
```

That was my first thought of how I access the source of one of the link elements. But it doesn't work with .source at the end.

```
 getNeighborNode(string) {
    for (const i of this.hierarchialGraph.links) {
      if (string === this.hierarchialGraph.links[i].source) {
        ...
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have many ways to iterate over an array :

```
for (const link of this.hierarchialGraph.links) {
  // access to source : link.source
}


for (let i=0; i < this.hierarchialGraph.links.length; i++) {
  // access to source : this.hierarchialGraph.links[i].source
}

this.hierarchialGraph.links.forEach((link) => {
  // acces to source : link.source
});
```